# Admin vs non-admin controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller

So I recognize that Rails is a pretty opinionated language... which is why I feel like there's a definite Rails answer to this question. I'm trying to write the routing/ controllers for the following ADMIN user flow:

1. admin reviews/updates orders (has a `get` and `post`)
2. admin reviews/updates items in orders (has a `get` and `post`)
3. admin approves items in orders (has a `get` and `post`)
4. admin approves orders (has a `get` and `post`)

(Approval is not the same as update in this circumstance, so it's fairly important to differentiate that well)

This is literally a 1-2-3-4 step process flow, so I'm frankly thinking of doing everything under an `AdminsController`, with methods that follow the flow:

```
def step_1_get
  orders_to_show = Order.where(...)
end

def step_1_post
  order_params =
  # some kind of order update
end

def step_2_get
  items_to_show = Item.where(...)
end

def step_2_post
end

...
```

Similarly, I'd have all the views organized in steps under the admin folder.

I feel this would be much more clear than having a bunch of methods littered through the `OrdersController` and `ItemsController` even though I'm kind of breaking MVC. But again, what's the Railsy way of doing this?

Comment: seems pretty arbitrary to me. whatever keeps things DRY works.

Comment: You can do this with a form wizard without mangling your app into one controller which violates SRP